# Make sure that the "cp" command is executed properly

Tags: shell, cp

I make a backup copy of my files with `cp` command as described in this topic (Copy files in Linux, avoid the copy if files do exist in destination): https://superuser.com/a/1377730/1008457
Command is:

```
while true; do echo n; done | cp -Ri /origin /destination 2>/dev/null
```

That works fine. But how can I make sure that the copy process went without errors (read/write errors from hard disc drives)?
It is enough to consider that shell variable `$?` a `0` after copying returns?

Comment: Just to comment that your loop may be replaced by `yes n`, but that replacing `cp -Ri` by `cp -Rn` gets rid of the need of that bit completely (if using GNU tools).  The whole command therefore becomes `cp -Rn /origin /destination`.

Comment: Thanks! By doing `cp -Rn /origin /destination` I don't have to make redirecting `2>/dev/null`. In this way I will get the possibly errors by eventually corrupted discs. I hope that will solve my case.

Comment: Hmm... did you ever _have to_ make that redirection? It's unclear whether your question asks about _visual_ inspection of error messages, in which case just removing the redirection of error messages to `/dev/null` would be enough.

Comment: @Kusalananda - I did as suggested in the above link to `superuser`. However, I have done this only a few times. I used to use a `rsync` command before.

Comment: Is your question about _ensuring_ that the copy goes well, or about _noticing_ when it doesn't go well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cp` will return with exit status `0` if no errors happened, otherwise `1`. So yes, you can test this value into a script to decide if no errors happened.

Also currently you discard the standard error of the command with `2>/dev/null`. If you omit this, any error will be printed to the terminal, which is the default for `stdout` and `stderr`. Or you could capture `stderr` to a log file, with `2>path/to/log/file`.

---

Also, (as Kusalananda already [commented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/623817/make-sure-that-the-cp-command-is-executed-properly/623821#comment1166816_623817)) you can simplify your command using `-n`, `--no-clobber`, which means do not overwrite any destination.

```
cp -Rn origin destination 2>log_file
```

and right after that, if into a script, you can test `$?` for success.

Or you can use the standard `if` syntax:

```
if cp -Rn origin destination 2>log_file; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "Failed"
fi
```

or the abbreviation:

```
cp -Rn origin destination 2>log_file && echo "OK" || echo "Failed"
```

---

Also `-a` (instead of `-R`) seems useful for backup as it implements `-Rd`, to dereference links (see `man cp`)

Comment: Maybe `-a` should be preferred over `-R` for a backup as all metadata might be of importance in such case. Also an automated `cp ... && echo 'all okay' || echo 'ERROR'` would avoid forgetting to check.

Comment: @Fiximan - trully, I doing the following (a little modified) command: `while true; do echo n; done | cp -ai /origin/. /destination 2>/dev/null`

Comment: @Fiximan yes `-a` is good for backup, I see it implements `-Rd`, to dereference links too. Although I think `rsync` is preferable, in general.

Comment: @klpu39 it's better not to discard `2>`, just print it somewhere to see what went wrong (if error occured). Also `-n` is doing this, no need for the `while`, see existing suggestion in first comment of the question.

Comment: Is your question about _ensuring_ that the copy goes well (as stated in title), or about _noticing_ when it doesn't go well?   This answer has more to do with noticing errors.

Comment: @Kusalananda - I hope that I understood the main message of the answer (and comments) correctly. With the `-n` option of `cp` I will see (read/write) errors directly in the terminal. Thus, checking of `$?` is unnecessary.